# Emulate an `expand` with a TaskGroup in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

## Objective

I would like to have the following structure in my DAG Graph:

```
                ---- sleeper_1 ---- stringer_1 ----
               /                                   \
list_generator -----            ...            ----- printer
               \                                   /
                ---- sleeper_n ---- stringer_n ----
```

I want the `stringer_x` task to begin as soon as the `sleeper_x` task is finished, as the former only needs the output_data of the latter to process.
I have defined the tasks as follow (these are dummy tasks, they could technically be rearranged, but this is not the goal here):

```py
@task
def seconds_list_generator(n):
    return [x*5 for x in range(n)]

@task_group
def sleeper_stringer_group(seconds):
    @task
    def sleeper(s):
        sleep(s)
        return s

    @task
    def stringer(s):
        return f"Slept {s}, finished at {datetime.now()}"

    seconds_slept: int = sleeper(s=seconds)
    string_info: str = stringer(s=seconds_slept)
    return string_info

@task
def printer(string):
    print(string)
```

## Issue

I can't seem to find a way to generate the duplication of the group for every element in my list.

## What have I tried

I tried to use the `expand` method, but the `task_group` decorator doesn't seem to be implementing it.

```py
seconds_list = list_generator(n=5)
strings_list = sleeper_stringer_group.expand(seconds=seconds_list)
printer.expand(string=strings_list)
```

I tried recuperating the list from the `list_generator` task and iterating over it, but it raises a `TypeError: 'XComArg' object is not iterable` error. Obviously, the use of `map` yields the same error.
The answer accepted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70929009/airflow-parallel-tasks-with-subtasks) doesn't suit me for I need to pass data from the non-parallelized steps to the parallelized ones, and vice-versa. Additionally, [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-task-groups-in-airflow-2-0-d85b7517767e) isn't solving the issue either for the data passed to the groups is the same, and the group is duplicated a fixed amount of times.

Thanks to everyone reading and responding!

## Edit

There is a workaround, which is to not use `task_group`s, and defining the `sleeper_stringer_group` as a task (with the subtask not decorated). In this configuration, the use of `expand` is then possible.
Note: this obviously removes the ability to see the details of this task in AirFlow.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the similar issue, in 2.5.3 `task_group` decorator actually has the `.expand` implemented.